# Dll for use with Excel VBA and LibreOffice Calc Basic

Tags: c++, dll, libreoffice, basic, calc

I have windows 8 and with VS2017 I created a Dll1.dll in c ++ to be used in Excel(VBA) and Libreoffice/Calc (Basic).
The DLL contains a simple function that returns an integer.

I compile the project without registering the dll.

When I try to register the dll (regsvr32 "C:...\Dll1.dll") I get the message "The module was loaded but, but the entry point DllRegisterServer was not found".

Despite this message,

using Dll from VBA I can call the function that return the correct value:

```
Declare Function Test Lib "C:\...\Dll1.dll" () As Integer
Sub abc ()
    Call MsgBox(Test)
End Sub
```

using Dll from Basic-Calc, I get the message "BASIC runtime error. Error loading DLL file"

```
Declare Function Test Lib "C:\...\Dll1.dll" () As Integer
Sub abc
    msgbox (Test())
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

These are the project files:

***framework.h***

```
#pragma once
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
```

***pch.h***

```
#ifndef PCH_H
#define PCH_H
#include "framework.h"
#endif
```

***pch.cpp***

```
#include "pch.h"
```

***dllmain.cpp***

```
#include "pch.h"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

***Intestazione.h***

```
#pragma once
#ifdef DLL1_EXPORTS
#define DLL1_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL1_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
extern "C" DLL1_APIint Test();
```

***Origine.cpp***

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Intestazione.h"

int Test() {
    return 250;
}
```

Comment: Ensure that your DLL is compiled to 32 or 64 bit, then check whether MSOffice and Libre Office are 32 or 64 bit apps. The bit depth of a DLL should be the same as for an application.

Comment: You were right, compiling DLL to 64 bit it works. Thank you